# поиск подстроки в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Изучаю регулярные выражения и что-то запутался чуть в поиске подстроки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из строки

```
var str = 'file:///G:/papka/task/Final%20task%20-%20Current%202016/ww/images/catalog/catalog1.jpg' ;
```

найти подстроку `../images/catalog/catalog1.jpg`, где после слова **catalog** цифры могут быть от **1** до **100**.

Comment: А ничего, что принятый вами ответ берет любые цифры от 0 до 999, а в условиях задачи вы написали от 1 до 100 ? Мне вот ответ Visman больше понравился...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\/images\/catalog\/catalog\d{1,3}.jpg
```

Точки в начале доканкатенируете.

Answer (score 1):

В самом простом случае можно поступить следующим образом

```
/\/images\/catalog\/catalog[0-9]+.jpg$/
```

Comment: Зачем же на столько топорно отвечать, что даже контроля количества цифр нет.

Comment: Я не считаю, что зажимать значения, а не форму следует регулярными выражениями. Составил такое выражение намеренно, конкретное значение следует валидировать уже далее в коде, а не городить трехэтажные регулярные выражения - чем они проще, тем лучше всем окружающим. Не согласны - приведите свой ответ, а не вступайте в дискуссию с отвечающими.

Comment: Зачем свой, Visman отлично ответил

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то другие отвечающие не обратили внимание на условие

> цифры могут быть от 1 до 100.

Вариант от меня выглядит так:

```
%/images/catalog/catalog(?:[1-9]\d?|100)\.jpg%
```

где

`%` - выбрал такой ограничитель для регулярки, чтобы слеши не экранировать;

`(?:[1-9]\d?|100)` не захватываемая группа для числа от 1 до 100, тут:

- первая цифра не ноль `[1-9]` + вторая цифра `\d` может быть, а может и не быть `?` или `|` число `100`.

Тест тут https://regex101.com/r/wC4kX4/1

Comment: Лучше заэкранирйте слеши, у ТС судя по всему JS и там оно необходимо.

Comment: @Mike, пояснение написано -> `выбрал такой ограничитель для регулярки, чтобы слеши не экранировать;`. Разберется, думаю.